# Big and base point free divisor on surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex algebraic surface. Let $D$ be a divisor. Assume that $D$ is base point free. Then the linear system $|D|$ defines a morphism $$\varphi:X\to \mathbb{P}^N.$$

I wonder if the following is true.

> $\varphi$ is generically finite if and only if $D^2>0$.

The question comes when I read Friedman's *Algebraic Surfaces and Holomorphism Vector Bundles*. After defining *eventually base point free divisor* (p.21), there is a paragraph and I am stuck on the sentence

> ... (3rd line) We assume that $\varphi_{nD}$ is generically finite, or equivalently that $D$ is big. ...

The definition of big divisor is that $D^2>0$.

[image]

Comment: Yes, what you want is true. If the map is generically finite, then $D^2$ can be computed by choosing representatives of $D$ that avoid the contracted locus, so you get $\operatorname{deg} \varphi \cdot \operatorname{deg} \operatorname{im} \varphi$ points.

Comment: If the map is not generically finite then its image is a curve, and $D$ is pulled back from a basepoint-free linear system on the curve. Two general members of the linear system on the curve will be disjoint, so you get $D^2=0$ in this case.